# Deleting code and unit tests in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have been asked to create unit tests for code which I deleted from a java class (note this is not an API so I do not need to deprecate the code).

Assume you have a java class as per below, and you need to delete some code as commented below:

```
public class foo extends foobar {

protected void doStuff() {

   doMoreStuff();

   // Everything below needs to be deleted, including the doStuffToo() method

   Object o = null;
   doStuffToo(o);



}

public void doMoreStuff() {
   boolean a = true;
}

// this method needs to be deleted
public void doStuffToo(Object o) {
   o = new Object();
}



}
```

I am of the opinion that you should simply delete the test cases for the deleted code, however I am being told that I should write unit tests to check for the existence of the old code in the event there is a bad merge in the future.

What is considered best practice in the above example?

Comment: This question seems better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Even if you did that it wouldn't protect against bad merges. The test could always have the merge bungled too, so that the wrong version of the test appeared.

Comment: I think this is a pretty silly idea, although a tiny part of me understands the motivation. You could always write a test that uses reflection to test for the existence of the method... but IMO this is weird.

Comment: IMO you've done what you should have. If others depended on that method than they should have unit tests for said method. This would make their tests break, and they know exactly what to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully, you have unit tests in place for the doStuff method. Assuming you do, I would do the following:

1. Update the tests for the doStuff method to reflect what the new logic should do.
2. Run the doStuff tests and verify that they fail.
3. Delete the application code you have been asked to remove.
4. Re-run the doStuff tests and verify that they pass.
5. If the tests don't pass in step 4, analyse and refactor accordingly until they pass.
6. Remove the tests which test the deleted methods (you will have received a compiler error from step 3 anyway).

I would love to know what the unit tests that "check for the existence of the old code" would do and the benefit they would provide. I know what would happen to such code if left behind. It would remain in the code base and become redundant, causing confusion to new team members until a few years later when a wise person decides to remove them.

Anyway, your safety net is the doStuff tests which hopefully would catch any merge problems. If you have the tests under source control (I hope so!), then you can always revert to a previous revision of the code base to retrieve the deleted tests if required in the future.

Comment: James, this is precisely what I have done but was wondering if maybe I was missing something.

Comment: @bated Cool, well IMO you have done the correct thing.